# Is it possible to use both windows phone cameras at the same time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

While trying to use both cameras for windows phone app i am not able to display both cameras at the same time.. 
one of them freeze when the other is working. i used the same code that has been given for reference here: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
any suggestion or code that shows an example of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is not supported by the API. Opening an additional instance of the camera will close the previous one.

However, to behave nicely with battery usage, you should explicitly .Dispose the device as soon as you are done with it (instead of relying on the auto-close behavior).

(Note that some hardware actually shares resources between the FFC and the BFC, so even if the API allowed for it, it is still unlikely to work with the current version of the OS).

refer this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/cdefd4cb-94f8-4d98-a4b4-7671606815c6/can-i-use-frontcamera-and-primary-camera-at-the-same-time

but in the phone like S4 it is possible

refer this link

http://www.wpxbox.com/dual-shot-camera-apps-wp/

Comment: yeah, i guess is not possible to really do so, i been trying all day long and it keeps crashing, i wanted to do an app kind of like the s4... Thanks for the reference!